# WatchKit Extension - Unable to find image named “XXX” on Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

Ii'm just trying to set text into a WKInterfaceLabel but its telling me no image find with this name.

Here is the code

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *testTextBox;  
  _testTextBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", testString];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related with this code. You must check all WKIntefaceImage's names. if you have wrong one than this error appears like this. If you recheck all WKIntefaceImage's names you will see there is have a wrong one.

Comment: thanks. its so interesting. i was tried to everything but it wasnt gone. i check all and find one different named WKIntefaceImage.

Comment: In my case, I saw this error when my assets were incorrectly named Image.png (and added as 1x images) instead of retina images named Image@2x.png (and added as 2x images).

Answer (score 1):

click on the image file, you'll see "Target Membership" options on the right pane. Select all of them, Clean the build and try again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyOne still got the same issue:

Might by You copy cell in InterfaceBuilder with some old outlet or action connections.

So just remove old outlet connections and reconnect the new one.

I made the same issue, just try it!

Answer (score 0):

For me the above fixes, individually, didn't work.
Make sure your images end in "@2x" (before the extension .png/.jpg)
Drop them into the blue Assets folder/catalog.
Delete the app from your simulator or device (this solved it for both of them for me)

It looks like once you gum things up with bad naming it doesn't recover. Removing the app, fixing the naming and reimporting into the catalog fixed my issues.

Coding for the watch is still tough, and I rely on tips like this to get through the 'gotchas'.

Answer (score -1):

Clean the project and Delete your app in simulator, error will be gone.